# What do I need to do to get 'EXPORT RELEASE BUILD' to generate android app icon the way RUN command does in FlashBuilder 4.6?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I have been working on an app for a while now and noticed today that when I export release build the final app icon (on android device) isnt produced - it just defaults to the standard android icon...

but with the RUN command (the icon that is next to debug) it DOES generate the icon.  When I export for iOS the correct icon is also produced on an iphone Im testing on.

what do I need to do to get the icon to be generated when I 'export release build'?  Im using FB 4.6, Flex 4.6.0 SDK and heres the app icon info in my -app.xml file:

```
<icon>
    <image32x32>views/images/32.png</image32x32>
    <image36x36>views/images/36.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>views/images/48.png</image48x48>
    <image57x57>views/images/57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>views/images/72.png</image72x72>
    <image114x114>views/images/114.png</image114x114>
    <image128x128>views/images/128.png</image128x128>
</icon>
```

Comment: in case anyone else ever has same issue thought i'd update this... still never found the issue/cause.  appears to be cached somewhere the old / default android icon... i recreated in fb4.6 and started by creating icons and looked fine.  when I set the ID for the app it still used the incorrect icon.  with a new id it used the correct icon.

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system you are using ....
If MAC Or Window
Then you have to put all android required icon images in your project then try it ...meanwhile you can contact me or msg me stackoverflow here

```
     <icon>

    <image29x29>assets/x_29.png</image29x29>
    <image57x57>assets/icon.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>assets/x_72.png</image72x72>
    <image76x76>assets/x_76.png</image76x76>
    <image100x100>assets/x_100.png</image100x100>
    <image114x114>assets/icon@2x.png</image114x114>
    <image120x120>assets/x_120.png</image120x120>
    <image128x128>assets/x_128.png</image128x128>
    <image144x144>assets/x_144.png</image144x144>
    <image152x152>assets/x_152.png</image152x152>
    <image512x512>assets/x_512</image512x512>

</icon>
```

Thanks